# Solo que acepte los números y la tecla de borrar en el evento de mi de mi TextBox Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

solo quiero que me acepte enteros en mi TextBox por mi evento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

e visto esto, digamen que es verdad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***y si no fuese el caso, algun metodo para que mi TextBox solo reconozca las teclas que tengan numeros***

Intente este metodo funciona y todo, pero a la hora de borrar con la tecla de borra no borra y con la tecla supr si borra.

```
public bool Numeros(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) == true)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    return e.Handled;
}
```

Comment: No se dónde viste lo de "TipoControl", pero no existe. Otra cosa es que crees tu propio control heredado de `TextBox` como es el ejemplo que pones en tu segunda imagen. Fíjate arriba que no es un `TextBox`, sino un `Globaltech,TextBoxControl...`

Comment: eso lo encuentro en el "Cuadro de herramientas ??"

Comment: Puede ser, pero no es un control standard. Alguien (si no has sido tu) ha importado ese control externo al cuadro de herramientas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, prueba este codigo:

```
private void txtNumero_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            SoloNumeros(e);
        }


        public bool SoloNumeros(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            return e.Handled;
        }
```

estoy seguro que te aceptara.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo usando el evento **KeyPress** del **TextBox**. Puedes crear este método que te valida que el valor de entrada es un número y lo llamas desde el evento KeyPress.

Desde el evento KeyPress del botón llama al método, pasale el parámetro **e** (KeyPressEventArgs) llamando el método. El **handled** si es igual a true significa que lo escribirá en el **TextBox** si es false (no se ha manejado) se colocará.

```
/// <summary>
/// Este método comprueba que los valores introducidos son sólo numéricos
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">Tecla precionada</param>
/// <returns>Retorna un valor de verdad</returns>
public bool validarNumeros(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) == true)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) == true)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    return e.Handled;
}
```

Se vería de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muy bueno... eres un **genio**.

Comment: Muchas gracias :D

Comment: note algo fuera de lo comun, y tengo duda, no puedo borrar con la tecla de borrar pero con el suprimir si funciona, ¿sabes algo?

Comment: como borrar?...

Comment: El problema es que tiene este codigo, que ciertas teclas no van a ser aceptadas por el manejador de eventos. Mas alla de eso, hace lo que OP pide

Comment: no entiendo el porque no lo acepta, hay alguna manera de activarlo ??
como el validar esa tecla

Comment: @RodrigoRodriguez el problema es que se esta fijando si la tecla que recibe se puede considerar un numero. Y no todo se puede considerar un numero, por ejemplo la tecla borrar. debe ser un codigo mas especializado para que te permita borrar, usar las flechas, puntos, comas y otras cosas que necesites. pero este es un buen comienzo para que experimentes.

Comment: a buscar mas entonces.

Comment: Hola Rodrigo. Lamento la tardanza en responder. Si te das cuenta si colocas char.{nada} te aparecerán más cosas como por ejemplo IsControl. Usa esa propiedad en un Else If para decirle que si es una tecla de control que pase a aceptarlo.

Comment: Agregue nuevo código a la respuesta. Puedes volver a ver como seria el procesos.